# Not able to export data into Excel using xlsxwriter library

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to iterate a For Loop such that the elements in the two lists get exported to excel in columns A and B. However, whenever I run the code it only displays a single number in column B row 1 (B1).

The entire code is too long so I'm attaching just a snippet of the code where I am stuck.

[This is what I'm getting in my excel file when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqs5p.png)

```
#Exporting data to Excel
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('efficient_front.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

i = 1
if company == first_company:
    for perc_return in returns:
        worksheet.write('A' + str(i) , perc_return)
        i =+ 1
else:
    for perc_return in returns:
        worksheet.write('B' + str(i), perc_return)
        i =+ 1

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: I assume this is what you wanted to achieve]

consider the given lists => prod_codes, ID_codes. The below code will write each list as a column in an excel sheet. The parameters of worksheet.write() are as shown below

> worksheet.write(row_number,column_number,value_to_be_written)

```
    prod_codes = [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006]
    ID_codes = [123,345,567,789,908,345]
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook('PATH for XLSX to be created') as workbook:
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("NAME_ME")
            for index,value in enumerate(ID_codes):
                   worksheet.write(index,0,value)
            
            for index,value in enumerate(prod_codes):
                   worksheet.write(index,1,value)
```

Please go through the official documentation, it's clear how to perform what you need to perform. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a silent syntax error in your code with `i =+ 1` instead of `i += 1`. The code translates to `i = +1` which is equivalent to `i = 1` so it doesn't iterate.

Here is an alternative way to structure you code with `enumerate()` and the (row, col) syntax of `worksheet.write()`:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('efficient_front.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

returns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
company = True
first_company = False

if company == first_company:
    col_num = 0
else:
    col_num = 1

for row_num, perc_return in enumerate(returns):
    worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, perc_return)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]